# How to create partition in NAND flash in am335x evm?

Tags: linux, partitioning

2 GB NAND flash in `am35x evm` has 8 partitions. If I want to add one more partition in this, how to do it?

If we access `ti-sdk` installed for this, then in `kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-am335xevm.c` there is `static struct mtd_partitions`, wherein we can add our own partition.Is this a right approach and if this is the case then how to decide the size. Other blocks are of 128k. Including a partition means shrinking the size of others, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will be adding our own partition by its name and offset in kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-am335xevm.c

```
 static struct mtd_partition am335x_nand_partitions[] = {
/* All the partition sizes are listed in terms of NAND block size */
 {  .name           = "SPL",
    .offset         = 0,                    /* Offset = 0x0 */
    .size           = SZ_128K,
    .mask_flags     = MTD_WRITEABLE,        /* force read-only */
 },
 {  .name           = "U-Boot",
    .offset         = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x80000 */
    .size           = 15 * SZ_128K,
    .mask_flags     = MTD_WRITEABLE,        /* force read-only */
 },

 {  .name           = "File System",
    .offset         = MTDPART_OFS_APPEND,   /* Offset = 0x780000 */
    .size           = MTDPART_SIZ_FULL,
 }
```